# Spock test cases fail when multiple tests involved with async client calls , but runs successfully when individually run

Tags: java, unit-testing, asynchronous, spock

The test scenario is to get the result from a mocked client service called asynchronously. Here, if I try and run the mentioned tests individually, they execute successfully. But when trying to build the project via `mvn clean install` , the success test case gives error.

How do I handle the exception case scenario so that it does not affect the expected method behavior test cases? Or possibly what is causing the issue with multiple async calls? 
How do I handle/shutdown the spawned up thread, or wait for its completion before starting the next client call?

```
// SERVICE CLASS
public String serviceMethod(String arg1, String arg2) { 
   return mockedclient.fetchDetails(arg1, arg2)
                 .toCompletableFuture()
                 .thenapplyasync(HashSet::new) // assuming the received response is a list
                 .get(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

```
//TEST CLASS
def " should return result retrieved from the client" () {
   given:
   def arg1 = "value1"
   def arg2 = "value2"

   def futureList = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.toList("RESULT"))
   def futureSet = new BlockingVariable<Set<String>>()

   when:
   def result = serviceMethod(arg1, arg2)

   then:
   1 * mockedClient.fetchDetails(_) >> futureList
   0 * futureList.thenApplyAsync(_) >> futureSet
   0 * futureSet.get(_,_) >> Collections.toSet("RESULT")
 }


def " should return empty response when result retrieved from the client" () {
   given:
   def arg1 = "value1"
   def arg2 = "value2"

   def futureList = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Collections.toList("RESULT"))
   def futureSet = new BlockingVariable<Set<String>>()


   when:
   def result = serviceMethod(arg1, arg2)

   then:
   1 * mockedClient.fetchDetails(_) >> CompletableFuture.runAsync( { throw new Exception("Failed to fetch broker Analyst details " } )
   0 * futureList.thenApplyAsync(_) >> futureSet
   0 * futureSet.get(_,_) >> Collections.toSet("RESULT")
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that your problem should be reproducible for others. Thus, it makes sense to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise you will only attract speculative answers because there could be many types of errors. Spock has several ways to help you with testing asynchronous code, such as `PollingConditions`, `AsyncConditions`, `BlockingVariable` and `BlockingVariable` (note the "s").

Comment: The basic thing is: If your test is done and some spawned threads are still running, Spock or the JVM are not magically knowing and waiting for all threads to finish but the test runner is being shut down. So make sure the test waits for whatever asynchronous result or side effect you are trying to verify. I can say more after seeing your MCVE. Besides, you are asking "how to handle the exception case scenario" but don't even show it here.

Comment: @kriegaex - Thanks for the inputs, hope the update gives a better understanding of the scenario I am trying to raise here. I tried setting the ```result``` as a ```blockingVariable``` , still facing the same issue.

Comment: Not really, sorry. I cannot compile and run your code.

Comment: Hi , thankyou for the responses you've provided. I am very new with Spock... hence the mistakes.  My use case itself changed, henceforth the testing scenario. I could somehow manage to get that done. But will keep in mind your inputs, before raising a query on SO. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer because you didn't provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) either. So I cannot reproduce your problem by copying, compiling and running your code fragments. But a few things strike me as odd:

- You just say something is not working but do not show any error messages and stacktraces.
- Your production service class uses `mockedclient`, at least the name is strange. Why would you use a mock in production or test something using a mock?
- `futureList` in both feature methods is not a mock but a real object. Thus, you cannot check interactions and return stubbed results like `0 * futureList.thenApplyAsync(_) >> futureSet` on it.
- `futureSet` in both feature methods is not a mock but a real object. Thus, you cannot check interactions and return stubbed results like `0 * futureSet.get(_,_) >> Collections.toSet("RESULT")` on it.
- In both feature methods you use a variable `mockedClient` but forgot to show where and how it is defined/initialised.

I assume your tests are throwing errors not just on Maven but also locally because, well - they contain bugs.